# 'Flush' and 'Abundant', are they interchangably?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, vocabulary

I've learned from my vocabulary app, that **flush** is synonymous with **abundant** in this context:

> The exam's passage is **flush** with difficult words, words that you may
> have learned only yesterday.

[image]

However, I feel uncertain. Cambridge Dictionary says **abundant** means [more than enough/plenty]. I couldn't find the meaning of **flush** that resembles **abundant**. Perhaps if there's any, it's [having a lot of money], according to Oxford dictionary.

Isn't it safe to just use **inundate** instead of **flush**? What do you think about the usage of **flush** in the sentence above? Is the app uses it correctly? And by the way, which part of speech is that? An adjective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not interchangable.  The words have different grammar, and different levels of formality.

Flush is a *less formal* and *less common* word than abundant.

You could paraphrase the phrase as

> There are abundant difficult words in the exam's passage.

but not "... is abundant with difficult words..."

There are also lots of other meanings to "flush" that don't mean "abundant"  (Flush the toilet, a flush in poker, the screw is flush with the wall)

"Inundate" is a verb, a different type of word.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with "... [is abundant with](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22is+abundant+with%22) difficult words...". But I do note that a specific collocation that seems particularly natural to me ([***is abundant with life***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+abundant+with+life&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20abundant%20with%20life%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cis%20abundant%20with%20life%3B%2Cc0)) only really seems to have gained significant traction in recent decades.

Comment: ...but there is a usage difference whereby we can say ***I'm flush*** to mean *I have **plenty of money***, but we can't say ***I'm abundant***. Nor can we say *There are **flush** difficult words in the exam's passage.*